# Copy Without Prefix s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have directory structures in s3 like

```
bucket/folder1/*/*.csv
```

Where the folder wildcard refers to a number of different folders containing csv files. 
I want to copy them at  without the prefix to

```
bucket/folder2/*.csv
```

Ex:
bucket/folder1/

```
s3distcp --src=s3://bucket/folder1/ --dests3://bucket/folder2/ --srcPattern=.*/csv
```

Results in the undesired structure of:

```
bucket/folder2/*/*.csv
```

I need a solution to copy in bulk that is scalable. Can I do this with s3distcp? Can I do this with aws s3 cp (without having to execute the aws s3 cp per file)?

Comment: What about the situation where you have `bucket/folder1/foo/file.csv` _and_ `bucket/folder1/bar/file.csv`? If both files were moved to `bucket/folder/file.csv`, they would overwrite each other.

Comment: The use case is to collapse the directory structure by copying to an empty folder.

Comment: Yes, but what if there are two files, in separate directories, with the same name? What would you like to have happen to those files? Which one should be kept and which one lost?

Comment: Each filename is a unique uuid and will never be the same as another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Apache Nifi to do this, changing the filename attribute of the flowfile (use regex to remove all of the path before the last '/') and writing with a prefix to the desired directory. It scales really well.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following CLI command

aws s3 sync s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME s3://DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME --recursive

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut to do what you wish, because you are manipulating the path to the objects.

You could instead write a little program to do it, such as:

```
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

# Get a list of objects in folder1
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET, Prefix='folder1')

# Copy files to folder2, keeping a flat hierarchy
for object in response['Contents']:
    key = object['Key']
    print(key)
    s3_client.copy_object(
        CopySource={'Bucket': BUCKET, 'Key': key},
        Bucket=BUCKET,
        Key = 'folder2' + key[key.rfind('/'):]
    )
```